# infinite series with Hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Can we get a closed form for the series

$\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{ t^k}{k!} \Gamma(k+a)\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2}){}_2F_1(k+a,k+\frac{1}{2};n+1,x)$

any hints or clues are welcomed.

Comment: $\Gamma(k+1)=k!$ cancels,right?Makes me think you have a misprint there.  Also, are $x$, $n$, and $t$ independent real (complex) variables or what?

Comment: yes, definitely true...just fixed...

Comment: Do you know any case (other than: all terms zero but finitely many) where it converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too wonder about convergence. You can rewrite it as 
$$\Gamma \left( a\right) \Gamma \left( 1/2\right) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left( a\right) _{j+k} \left( 1/2\right) _{j+k}}{\left( n+1\right) _{j}}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}\frac{x^{j}}{j!};$$
if you had an additional Pochhammer term indexed by k in the denominator, it would be Appel's $F_{4}$ function.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your LaTeX

Comment: @Tony: Thanks, I see you have expanded the Gaussian Hypergeometric function as well. Are you familiar with any software that computes Appel's function? 

Comment: No.  Matlab does not have built-in hypergeometric functions beyond the Gaussian hypergeometric function.  Mathematica only has $F_{1}$. The python package mpmath computes all 4 Appel functions, although I have not used it myself, so I can't vouch for it.  But again, your expression is not $F_{4}$; I don't think it matches any listed multivariate hypergeometric function, and I don't think it will converge in general.